# Facebook SDK : 'Apps that target Android API 30+ (Android 11+) cannot call Facebook native apps unless the package visibility needs are declared'

Tags: android, facebook, kotlin, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

I use the Android Facebook SDK. I get the following message in Logcat:

```
com.facebook.internal.NativeProtocol: Apps that target Android API 30+ (Android 11+) cannot call Facebook native apps unless the package visibility needs are declared. Please follow https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/troubleshooting/#faq_267321845055988 to make the declaration.
```

What does that mean? Do I need to add in the manifest the item mentioned on facebook page mentioned in this error message, that is to say :

```
<manifest package="com.example.app"> <queries> <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.katana.provider.PlatformProvider" /> </queries> ... </manifest>
```

Nota: I use no facebook dialog boxes in my app.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I also added the queries tag as it says in description of this error/warning and it didn't help. My app was simply using facebook as login to my app.

After checking what its about, it turns out that when you run this code:
`fbButton.setLoginBehavior(LoginBehavior.NATIVE_ONLY);`

`NATIVE_ONLY` option description is:

> Specifies that login should only attempt to login using a native app in the Facebook Family of Apps.

Just installing facebook app didn't help, so changed it to:
`fbButton.setLoginBehavior(LoginBehavior.NATIVE_WITH_FALLBACK);`

This way it will try native only approach, if it fails then try web dialog auth.
And now it fallbacks to web dialog auth and works.

Answer (score -2):

Apps that target Android API 30+ (Android 11+) cannot call Facebook native apps unless the package visibility needs are declared  in manifest file under `<menifest>` tag

```
    <queries>
    <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.katana.provider.PlatformProvider" />
    <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.orca.provider.PlatformProvider" />
</queries>
```

Comment: this did nothing for me

Comment: This answer did nothing for me too. Have you got any other working solutions?

Comment: Yep, this is answer is directly from Meta, but it doesn't solve the problem. Very frustrating.

Answer (score -2):

I had to add the queries block as per Meta documentation as in the answer above but I still got the package visibility error when I tried to share content from my app with Facebook. I uninstalled the Facebook app on my device and reinstalled it with the latest version and then it worked.

```
<queries>
    <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.katana.provider.PlatformProvider" />
    <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.orca.provider.PlatformProvider" />
</queries>
```

Answer (score -3):

Kindly update your Facebook library version if it was not already updated.

Here is an updated version of Facebook SDK.

```
implementation("com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:14.1.1") {
    because("Social Media Login integration")
}
```

Thank you.